# How to create multi level subgroups in organic groups?

Tags: organic-groups, entities, group

I Need to create multi level of subgroups in organic groups like

[image]

like a tree. I don't know how to create using organic groups. Can anyone suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there is a module for this: [Subgroups for Organic groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og_subgroups)

According to the module description,

> This module enables a user with the proper permissions to build group
>   hierarchies (or tree) by nesting groups under other groups. Simple or
>   complex group hierarchies can be easily created.

Comment: Thank you, I installed this module, but it not working properly. I'm new to this group modules

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have organic groups installed and working:

1. Lets assume your content type for organic groups is called "group"
2. Edit this content type via: admin/structure/types/manage/group
3. Click on the "Organic Groups" tab for the content type.
4. Select the "Group content" field in addition to "Group". This ensures that the "Group" content type can also now be part of a group.
5. Save the content type.

That's all you need to do.

Additionally, installing [og_groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og_subgroups) module 
enables propagation of settings, permissions etc. It is only needed if you want to so do.

If you want to see the tree hierarchically, you made need to create views using somethign like [views_tree](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_tree)